# Change background color and font of tool tip for ASP. Net controls

Tags: asp.net

For ASP.Net controls, how to change background color, font name, size, font color for tool tips? Is it possible to add background image for tool tips instead of the default yellow color background?

Comment: How are you currently implementing your tooltips? i.e using title /.Tooltip  / CSS ?? some sample code maybe?

Comment: I have just used tooltip property in ASP.Net controls to change the text of tool tip being displayed. Eg: txtPassword.ToolTip="Password should have at least one special character and number.";

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this question:  [How to change the background color of the tooltip for a control available inside gridview on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781710/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-tooltip-for-a-control-available-inside)

Basically, you can't change the default tooltip colors.  You have to use something custom.  There are lots of jQuery and CSS approaches to this.  The default tooltips are controlled by the browser, and aren't available for customization.