# How to change the background color of the tooltip for a control available inside gridview on hover

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a `linkbutton` control inside `gridview itemtemplate`.

i want to customize the default `tooltip` view of that `linkbutton` control. How can i achieve this ?
Here is my Grid and already it is binded data from another function.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridReports" runat="server" 
              OnRowDataBound="GridReports_RowDataBound"
              DataKeyNames="SubmitID" ShowFooter="true" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false">

 <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>Department Lead</HeaderTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyleWidth100" />
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HiddenField ID="LabelDepartmentLead" 
               Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepartmentLead")%>'
               runat="server" />
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonView" Text="View" 
               Font-Underline="false" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Blue" 
               runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="EditItemStyle" />
  </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my DataBound where i am assigning the tooltip for the LinkButton control (which is the default tooltip style).

```
protected void GridReports_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
    {
        HiddenField LabelDepartmentLead = 
                   (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("LabelDepartmentLead");
        LinkButton LinkButtonView = 
                   (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButtonView");
        if (LabelDepartmentLead.Value == string.Empty)
        {
            LabelDepartmentLead.Value = "No Department Leads";
        }
        LinkButtonView.ToolTip = LabelDepartmentLead.Value;
    }
}
```

How can i identify the tooltip style and customize it. Please help!

Comment: It is not possible as such as tooltips are actually rendered as `title` attribute for most (all?) controls if I'm not mistaken, and the "tooltip" that is showed by browser displaying the text of this `title` attribute is impossible to style. If you want a "tooltip like" functionality, you'll need to implement it with Javascript/CSS

Comment: If it's a javascript tooltip you will need to track down it's assets. Some tooltips use javascript for styling only, some have css rules also. inspect the DOM in browser console for clues

Comment: @charlietfl : It's default tooltip for the control. i am not using any javascript to change it. is the possible to change the tooltip from code behind ?

Comment: If it uses browser default title tooltip you can't style that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Combining Javascript and CSS i am able to achieve this.Code behind remains same as defined in the question.

Posting here - might be helpful for others.

**ItemTemplate**

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="LabelDepartmentLead" 
          Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepartmentLead")%>'
          runat="server" />
     <asp:LinkButton  ID="LinkButtonView" Text="View" Font-Underline="false"
          Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Blue" runat="server"
          onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" ToolTip="Test" 
          onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function showTooltip(control) {
         var ttext = control.title;
         var tt = document.createElement('SPAN');
         var tnode = document.createTextNode(ttext);
         tt.appendChild(tnode);
         control.parentNode.insertBefore(tt, control.nextSibling);
         tt.className = "tooltipCss";
         control.title = "";
     }

     function hideTooltip(control) {
         var ttext = control.nextSibling.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         control.parentNode.removeChild(control.nextSibling);
         control.title = ttext;
     }

     $(function () {
         $('[title]').tooltip({
             content: function () {
                 var element = $(this);
                 return element.attr('title')
             }
         });
     });

</script>
```

**css**

```
<style>
  .tooltipCss
   {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      margin: 1em;
      padding: 3px;
      background: #A4D162;
      font-family: Trebuchet MS;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: black;
      font-size: 11px;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery library.

Click on the view source link : http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Comment: there are lots of tooltips that don't require the overhead of jQueryUI and are far more flexible